# Look rotation 2d equivalent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(path.lookPoints[pathIndex] - transform.position);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, turnSpeed);
transform.Translate(Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime,Space.Self)
```

I want to replace the piece of code above with a 2d equivalent but everything i found on the internet seems to not help me at all. Any help?

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: I have a pathfinding algorithm, and it uses nodes, i want to move forward to each node. I want to achive this by rotating my gameobject towards each node. I am not able to gradualy rotate my gameobject, when moving, until it will face and eventualy reach the target

Comment: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: What vector points through the front of your sprite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you know your front vector, you can use `Quaternion.FromToRotation` to get the `targetRotation` you need to point the front at the next point in your path.

```
Vector3 frontVector = Vector3.right; // Set your front vector here

Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(frontVector, 
        path.lookPoints[pathIndex] - transform.position);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, turnSpeed);
transform.Translate(Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime,Space.Self)
```